# Is it possible to run multiple functions in one request

Tags: sendgrid

Newbie here with limited to no history with coding.

Attempting to build an email template and I want to know if it is possible to run multiple function in one request?  I am providing some test data below to try and better explain what is needed

Custom Field 1 - Score_A - Value can be between 1 and 10 This will vary based on the customer being emailed)

Custom Field 2 - Score_B - Value can be between 1 and 10

Custom Field 3 - Score_C - Value can be between 1 and 10

Custom Field 4 - Score_D - Value can be between 1 and 10

I need the code to search across all four custom fields and if any of the values of these custom fields is more than 5 I want to the outcome to read "Good", if any of the vales of the custom field are below 5 I want the outcome to read "Bad". I do not want out outcome for each custom field, I just need 1 outcome for each email.

e.g. if

Score_A=6

Score_B=9

Score_C=10

Score_D=8

The outcome in the email should read "Good"

But if

Score_A=2

Score_B=9

Score_C=10

Score_D=8

The outcome should read "Bad"

Comment: You say, "in a request", but you're also talking about email templates. Are you trying to do this within the template itself, or in code that is making a request to the API before sending an email?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.